# Проблема с реализацией сортировки вставками js

Tags: javascript, сортировка, случайные-числа

Имею задачу написать на js код, который описывал бы сортировку вставками массива, заполненного случайными числами от 1 до 100.

Для заполнения использовал метод `Math.Random()`.

При заполнении таким способом получаю массив:

```
[8,32,2,17,28,24,57,11,22,25]
```

после сортировки имею массив:

```
[11,17,2,22,24,25,28,32,57,8]
```

где "2" и "8" находятся не на своих местах, что не корректно (по крайней мере, я так считаю).

При заполнении "ручками" этого же массива, после сортировки имеем:

```
[2,8,11,17,22,24,25,28,32,57]
```

что верно.

**Вопрос:**
Что же не так с числами которые генерирует Math.Random() и почему при сортировке этих чисел они вычисляются некорректно?

Код:

```js
     // create an initial array
    
     let ourArray = [10]; 
    
     for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
     {
     ourArray[i] = [Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1]  // does not work if it fills like that
     }
    
    // ourArray = [2, 8, 11, 17, 22, 24, 25, 28, 32, 57];  //  <--- works with that
    
    console.log("Before sort");
    
    console.log(ourArray.join());
    
    console.log("After sort");
    
    // timer variable
    
    let time = performance.now();
    
    // Insertion Sort
    
    for (let i = 1; i < ourArray.length; i++) {
      const current = ourArray[i];
      let j = i;
      while (j > 0 && ourArray[j - 1] > current) {
          ourArray[j] = ourArray[j - 1];
          j--;
    
      }
      ourArray[j] = current;
    
    }
    
    console.log(ourArray.join()) 
    
    // perfomance stats
    
    time = performance.now() - time;
    console.log('Operating time in microseconds = ', time);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите квадратные скобки в правой части:

```
ourArray[i] = [Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1]
```

Вы присваиваете каждому элементу  массива `ourArray` массив из одного случайного числа, которые в дальнейшем сравниваются как строки.

---

Для вывода массива в консоль лучше использовать просто

```
console.log(ourArray);
```

или более компактно

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(ourArray));
```

---

И `-1` в Ваших вычислениях `Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1` не нужна.